# Switch from spark to pay as you go

Tags: firebase

Hi ok so I have not started the project but it will use firebase I will use the free spark plan but if more users join that the plan can handle if I switch to the pay as you go is there code that I need to change or will everything stay the same? Please help thank you

If I didn't ask this question right I am sorry I am new to stackoverflow...

Comment: It would seem that this information is likely available on Spark's website. I would research there first, and if you have a more specific question about your findings, update your question.

Answer (score 0):

Any Firebase project can be on any [pricing plan](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), and you can switch between plans as needed.

From the Firebase [pricing FAQ](https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#pricing):

> Can I upgrade, downgrade, or cancel at any time?
>
> Yes, you can upgrade, downgrade, or cancel at any time. Note that we don't provide prorated refunds for downgrades or cancellations. This means that if you downgrade or cancel before the end of your billing period, you still pay for the remainder of the month.

Note that the blaze/pay-as-you-go plan includes the same free quota as the limits of the spark/free plan.

Comment: Thx man so basically I can switch from different plans without need to change code and everything